# Verilog output is hiZ in testbench

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, modelsim

I'm new to verilog and modelsim. I'm having trouble with my AND and OR modules in this particular testbench. The output is always Z(hi impedance)

```
    module mux2to1_tb();
  reg[1:0] r0,r1;
  reg r2;
  wire[1:0] out;

  initial
  begin
    r0=1;
    r1=3;
    r2=0;
    #10;
    r2=1;
    #10;
  end

  mux tm(r0,r1,r2,out);

endmodule
```

here is the mux module

```
module mux(d0,d1,s0,out);
  input[1:0]d0,d1;
  input s0;
  output[1:0] out;
  wire [1:0]w1,w2,w3,w4;

  assign w4[0]=s0;
  assign w4[1]=s0;

  inv2bit M0(w4,w3);
  and2bit M1(d0,w3,w1);
  and2bit M2(d1,w4,w2);
  or2bit M3(w1,w2,out);

endmodule

  /*assign w3= ~w4;
  assign w1= d0&w3;
  assign w2= d1&w4;
  assign out= w1|w2;*/
```

this is the or module

```
module or2bit(iA,iB,out);

  input iA,iB;
  output out;

  assign out= iA|iB;

endmodule
```

this is the inverter module

```
module inv2bit(i1,out);

input i1;
output out;

  assign out= ~i1;

endmodule
```

Comment: I added the module codes to the post, not sure if I should post the AND module as well because it's exactly like the OR module aside from the operator.

Comment: You try to connect 2-bit signals to 1-bit ports in your inv, and and or modules.  Don't you get warnings for that?  For example: `w4[1:0]` to `i1` in `inv2bit`.  This is why it is important to post your complete code with exact error/warning message.

Comment: Yup, setting my modules' inputs and outputs to 2-bits worked. Strangely it gave no error when I connected them before this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared the `out` signal as a `wire` in your testbench, and you connected it to the `out` `output` port of your `mux` module.  However, the `out` signal in `mux` is undriven (it is not connected to anything else).  In Verilog, `wire` signals default to the `z` value.

In `mux` you have an undeclared signal named `outX`.  Is this `X` a typo?  In other words, `out` and `outX` are two different signals.  If you rename `outX` as `out` everywhere, the `out` will be connected.

UPDATE:  You have confirmed the `X` was a typo, and updated the Question accordingly.  That problem is solved.

Since you added the inv/and/or module code to the Question, we can see that you try to connect 2-bit signals to 1-bit ports in your submodules. For example: `w4[1:0]` to `i1` in `inv2bit`.  You need to change the port declarations to be 2-bit wide, such as:

```
input  [1:0] i1;
output [1:0] out;
```